# Simple examples continuous RVs $X_1, X_2$, with the same c.d.f $F(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same c.d.f. $F(x)$.

This means that the p.d.fs of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are almost everywhere equal.

I am having a hard time coming up with two functions which are:

1. Continuous.
2. Different only at a finite number of points.

This becomes particularly relevant when we assume that $X_1, X_2$ are independent, and consider a new R.V. $Y = \max\{X_1, X_2\}$. Note that $\{Y < x\}  = \{X_1 < x\} \cap \{X_2 < x\}$. Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, then $F(x)^2 = P(\{X_1 < x\} \cap \{X_2 < x\}) = P(Y < x) = G(x)$, where $G(x)$ is the c.d.f of $Y$. The p.d.f of $y$ is then:

$$ G'(x) = 2F(x)F'(x) = 2F(x)f(x) = g(x) $$

What is $f(x)$? Well, it is one of $f_1(x)$ or $f_2(x)$. It doesn't quite matter which it is, because both are densities with behaviour almost everywhere equal.

Can you provide me with an example of two p.d.fs (as simple as possible) which are almost everywhere equal? I'd like to try my hand at visualizing how $g(x)$ changes depending on the choice of $f(x)$.

Comment: If two functions are continuous and equal on a dense set, then they are equal everywhere. Thus you cannot find two continuous functions which are equal everywhere except for finitely many points. This being said, there is no reason pdfs need to be continuous. In fact, pdfs really only need to be defined up to sets of measure zero. So take any pdf and modify it however you want on a set of measure zero, and you will still get the same cdf.

Comment: @User8128 Ok, makes sense. I suppose when we say "continuous R.V." we mean that the sample space over which it is defined is continuous, not that the p.d.f itself is continuous?

Comment: A R.V. is continuous exactly when its distribution function is continuous.  They need not even _have_ density functions, even though the ones described in textbooks usually do.

Comment: @user89 It does not make sense to say that a sample space is continuous. A sample space is a set, not a function. A random variable $X$ is continuous if it admits a density function $f_X$ such that $\mathbb P(X\leqslant x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t)\ \mathsf dt$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.